# OAuth 2.0: What is the advantage of authorization_code grant flow over Implicit grant flow?

Tags: authorization, oauth2

I'm not able to appreciate what is the advantage of having a autorization_code given to the client and then exchanging this for access token on webapp side. Instead why not just give access_token to the client and ask client to pass on this info to webapp to access secured resources. This is what happens in Implicit grant anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can do that, and in fact it's a supported flow as you mentioned. However, the point of the code is to prevent the client itself from having access to the token. This prevents stealing or leaking of the token because it's confined to the internals of the web app itself, instead of shared around with whoever needs to use the service.

Remember that the flows apply to different scenarios.

Implicit flows are used when you need access to the token, but don't/can't trust the client such as an app running locally on a user's machine -- a malicious user could easily impersonate the client.

Code flows are used when you can trust and verify the client because, for example, it's hosted on a remote machine you don't have access to.

Comment: Thanks @steve. PKCE flow makes both access_token and refresh_token available to the client. Doesn’t it have same security issues?